# PHP: strict standard error in a customised menu

Tags: php

Kindly help correct the code below:

```
> PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/mods/Controller/Menu.php on line 15
```

The code is as below:

```
public function __call($function, $parameters){
    $categoria = strtolower(str_replace('Action',NULL,$function));
    $platillo = strtolower(array_pop( array_flip($_GET)));//line 15
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you perhaps passing a function as the $function variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_pop` requires a reference to a variable.  A reference means it has to be a variable - i.e. you can do:

```
$x = ["a", "b"];
array_pop($x);
```

but not

```
array_pop(["a","b"]);
```

So, to fix your issue, you would do:

```
$flipped_get = array_flip($_GET);
$platillo = strtolower(array_pop($flipped_get));//line 15
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, it works perfectly